# Is possible to create a hash code using a string on JS?

Tags: javascript, hash, hashcode

good day, exit a method to create a hash code of 15 characters with just a string using javaScript??

i mean i would like to create something like this :

```
 'd6fe8c82fb0abac17a702fd2a94eff37'
```

Just using a simple string, but need to have exactly 15 characters and if i want to use the same function in another string should be the same just 15 characters..

Im working on ES6

I'm a front end developer so i don't have any idea how to do this.. if anyone can help me i will appreciate it a lot.

Comment: How is the question related to java?

Comment: Are you essentially trying to create a function that accepts a string and returns a hash of the input string with a length of 15?

Comment: @RamilAmparo yes :)